# 14 candlestick difference between version 4 and 2 pine script

Tags: pine-script

This code is a version of two pine scripts

```
//Author - Chandan Kumar
//Thanks to Rajandran of www.marketcalls.in for original supertrend script
//Multi time frame supertrend - 6 timeframe supertrends in one chart
study("Multitimeframe Supertrend", overlay = true)

Factor=input(4, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd=input(10, minval=1,maxval = 100)

Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))

TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown

Trend15 = security(tickerid,"15",Trend)
Trend30 = security(tickerid,"30",Trend)
Trend60 = security(tickerid,"60",Trend)
Trend120 = security(tickerid,"120",Trend)
Trend240 = security(tickerid,"240",Trend)
TrendD = security(tickerid,"D",Trend)
TrendW = security(tickerid,"W",Trend)

Tsl15 = security(tickerid,"15",Tsl)
Tsl30 = security(tickerid,"15",Tsl)
Tsl60 = security(tickerid,"60",Tsl)
Tsl120 = security(tickerid,"120",Tsl)
Tsl240 = security(tickerid,"240",Tsl)
TslD = security(tickerid,"D",Tsl)
TslW = security(tickerid,"W",Tsl)

//linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red
linecolor15 = Trend15 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor30 = Trend30 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor60 = Trend60 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor120 = Trend120 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor240 = Trend240 == 1 ? green : red
linecolorD = TrendD == 1 ? green : red
linecolorW = TrendW == 1 ? green : red

plot(Tsl15, color = linecolor15 , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend15")
plot(Tsl30, color = linecolor30 , style = linebr , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend30")
plot(Tsl60, color = linecolor60 , style = circles, linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend60")
plot(Tsl120, color = linecolor120 , style = cross,linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend120")
plot(Tsl240, color = linecolor240 , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend240")
plot(TslD, color = linecolorD , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrendD")
plot(TslW, color = linecolorW , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrendW")
//plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,green,0,0)
//plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0)
//plot(Trend==1 and Trend[1]==-1,color = linecolor, style = circles, linewidth = 3,title="Trend")

//plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
//plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
```

I was able to convert this to version 4
But there is a problem

```
//@version=4
//Multi time frame supertrend - 6 timeframe supertrends in one chart
study("Multitimeframe Supertrend", overlay = true)

Factor=input(4, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd=input(10, minval=1,maxval = 100)

Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))

st() =>
    int Trend = na, float TrendUp = na, float TrendDown = na
    TrendUp:=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
    TrendDown:=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
    Trend := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
    Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown
    [Trend, Tsl]

[Trend15, Tsl15] = security(syminfo.tickerid,"15", st())
[Trend30, Tsl30] = security(syminfo.tickerid,"30", st())
[Trend60, Tsl60] = security(syminfo.tickerid,"60", st())
[Trend120, Tsl120] = security(syminfo.tickerid,"120", st())
[Trend240, Tsl240] = security(syminfo.tickerid,"240", st())
[TrendD, TslD] = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", st())
[TrendW, TslW] = security(syminfo.tickerid,"W", st())


// linecolor = Trend == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor15 = Trend15 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor30 = Trend30 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor60 = Trend60 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor120 = Trend120 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor240 = Trend240 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolorD = TrendD == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolorW = TrendW == 1 ? color.green : color.red

plot(Tsl15, color = linecolor15 , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend15")
plot(Tsl30, color = linecolor30 , style = plot.style_linebr , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend30")
plot(Tsl60, color = linecolor60 , style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend60")
plot(Tsl120, color = linecolor120 , style = plot.style_cross,linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend120")
plot(Tsl240, color = linecolor240 , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend240")
plot(TslD, color = linecolorD , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrendD")
plot(TslW, color = linecolorW , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrendW")
//plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,color.green,0,0)
//plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, color.red,0,0)
//plot(Trend==1 and Trend[1]==-1,color = linecolor, style = circles, linewidth = 3,title="Trend")

//plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
//plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=color.red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
```

There is only one problem left

Code 14 candle signals later than the original code

In the original code the tickerid for tsl30 is fifteen

In the new code, tickerid for tsl30 is 30
I do not know how to separate it ( Maybe that's the problem )

[An image that shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpR1Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add `lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on` to each `security()` call and the v4 script should work the same way the v2 one does.

More information can be found in [this User Manual article](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_version_3_migration_guide.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed).

Comment: Thank you very much buddy